# Creating a collection with validation in MongoDB 3.4 using Java

Tags: java, json, mongodb, validation, mongodb-query

I am trying to create a collection with validation in MongoDB(3.4) via Java.

This is working fine when executed in the shell:

```
  db.createCollection( "accounts",
   {
      validator: { $and:
         [
            { username: { $type: "string" } },
            { email: { $regex: /@*\.*$/ } },
            { password: { $type: "string" } }
         ]
      }
   }
)
```

So now I wanted to create the same collection with that validation in java. Sadly the previous answers I have found here are using deprecated methods.

This is what I tried since the validator field is an option field.

```
//String createDatabase = "{ 'validator': { '$and':[{ 'username': { '$type': 'string' } },{ 'email': { '$regex': '@*.*$' } },{ 'password': { '$type': 'string' } }]}}";
String createDatabase =  " { \"validator\": { \"$and\":[{ \"username\": { \"$type\": \"string\" } },{ \"email\": { \"$regex\": \"@*.*$\" } },{ \"password\": { \"$type\": \"string\" } }]}}";
JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
DBObject dbobj= (DBObject) JSON.parse(createDatabase);
getMongoClient().getDatabase(DATABASE_NAME).createCollection(collectionName, new CreateCollectionOptions().validationOptions(new ValidationOptions().validator((Bson) dbobj)) );
```

This is the exception I got. I assume that's because somehow the json cannot be parsed, I checked back if it's valid and it should be.

```
   {
      "validator": { "$and":
         [
            { "username": { "$type": "string" } },
            { "email": { "$regex": "@*.*$" } },
            { "password": { "$type": "string" } }
         ]
      }
   }
```

Above is the json that I tried to parse.

```
 com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 2: 'unknown operator: $and' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "unknown operator: $and", "code" : 2, "codeName" : "BadValue" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use the Filters utility class API to build the validator as it described in [the documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/tutorials/databases-collections/#document-validation). Here is the code:

```
    Bson username = Filters.type("username", BsonType.STRING);
    Bson email = Filters.regex("email", "@*.*$");
    Bson password = Filters.type("password", BsonType.STRING);

    Bson validator = Filters.and(username, email, password);

    ValidationOptions validationOptions = new ValidationOptions()
                                          .validator(validator);
    database.createCollection("accounts", new CreateCollectionOptions()
                                          .validationOptions(validationOptions));
```

It creates a collection with validation on MongoDB 3.4.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was searching for!